JetBrains IDE Soft-wrap these file syntax question
I am fairly new to the PhpStorm IDE and I want to be able to auto soft wrap all editors so I am trying to configure the Soft-wrap these files: option.  The instructions below the text box state "Use * and ? as wildcards and ; to separate pattens"  I have this written in the box.

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with what I have written?
I tried using *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc; *.php; *.js; ,*.html,*.sql
I'm not sure if the issue is not using the ? symbol somewhere in this or why my .php and .sql files will not automatically soft-wrap?


Why not just use * and soft-wrap every file? 2) Anyway -- I see commas , in your pattern, so it seems wrong. So try *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc; *.php; *.js; *.html; *.sql -- seems to work OK for me (tested in a single .html file -- used that pattern with and without *.html; part)


You have faulty , (commas) around « html ».
